# Abort early in a fold

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What's the best way to terminate a fold early? As a simplified example, imagine I want to sum up the numbers in an `Iterable`, but if I encounter something I'm not expecting (say an odd number) I might want to terminate. This is a first approximation

```
def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  nums.foldLeft (Some(0): Option[Int]) {
    case (Some(s), n) if n % 2 == 0 => Some(s + n)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

However, this solution is pretty ugly (as in, if I did a .foreach and a return -- it'd be much cleaner and clearer) and worst of all, it traverses the entire iterable even if it encounters a non-even number.

So what would be the best way to write a fold like this, that terminates early? Should I just go and write this recursively, or is there a more accepted way?

Comment: Do you want to terminate and record the intermediate answer ?

Comment: In this case, no. But in a slightly more general case I might want to return an Either that has an error or something

Comment: There is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595427/break-or-shortcircuit-a-fold-in-scala

Comment: This reply about breaking out of loops might also be found useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2742941/1307721

Answer (score 71, accepted):

My first choice would usually be to use recursion.  It is only moderately less compact, is potentially faster (certainly no slower), and in early termination can make the logic more clear.  In this case you need nested defs which is a little awkward:

```
def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]) = {
  def sumEven(it: Iterator[Int], n: Int): Option[Int] = {
    if (it.hasNext) {
      val x = it.next
      if ((x % 2) == 0) sumEven(it, n+x) else None
    }
    else Some(n)
  }
  sumEven(nums.iterator, 0)
}
```

My second choice would be to use `return`, as it keeps everything else intact and you only need to wrap the fold in a `def` so you have something to return from--in this case, you already have a method, so:

```
def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  Some(nums.foldLeft(0){ (n,x) =>
    if ((n % 2) != 0) return None
    n+x
  })
}
```

which in this particular case is a lot more compact than recursion (though we got especially unlucky with recursion since we had to do an iterable/iterator transformation).  The jumpy control flow is something to avoid when all else is equal, but here it's not.  No harm in using it in cases where it's valuable.

If I was doing this often and wanted it within the middle of a method somewhere (so I couldn't just use return), I would probably use exception-handling to generate non-local control flow.  That is, after all, what it is good at, and error handling is not the only time it's useful.  The only trick is to avoid generating a stack trace (which is really slow), and that's easy because the trait `NoStackTrace` and its child trait `ControlThrowable` already do that for you.  Scala already uses this internally (in fact, that's how it implements the return from inside the fold!).  Let's make our own (can't be nested, though one could fix that):

```
import scala.util.control.ControlThrowable
case class Returned[A](value: A) extends ControlThrowable {}
def shortcut[A](a: => A) = try { a } catch { case Returned(v) => v }

def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]) = shortcut{
  Option(nums.foldLeft(0){ (n,x) =>
    if ((x % 2) != 0) throw Returned(None)
    n+x
  })
}
```

Here of course using `return` is better, but note that you could put `shortcut` anywhere, not just wrapping an entire method.

Next in line for me would be to re-implement fold (either myself or to find a library that does it) so that it could signal early termination.  The two natural ways of doing this are to not propagate the value but an `Option` containing the value, where `None` signifies termination; or to use a second indicator function that signals completion.  The Scalaz lazy fold shown by Kim Stebel already covers the first case, so I'll show the second (with a mutable implementation):

```
def foldOrFail[A,B](it: Iterable[A])(zero: B)(fail: A => Boolean)(f: (B,A) => B): Option[B] = {
  val ii = it.iterator
  var b = zero
  while (ii.hasNext) {
    val x = ii.next
    if (fail(x)) return None
    b = f(b,x)
  }
  Some(b)
}

def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]) = foldOrFail(nums)(0)(_ % 2 != 0)(_ + _)
```

(Whether you implement the termination by recursion, return, laziness, etc. is up to you.)

I think that covers the main reasonable variants; there are some other options also, but I'm not sure why one would use them in this case.  (`Iterator` itself would work well if it had a `findOrPrevious`, but it doesn't, and the extra work it takes to do that by hand makes it a silly option to use here.)

Comment: The `foldOrFail` is exactly what I had come up with when thinking about the question. No reason not to use a mutable iterator and a while loop in the implementation IMO, when all nicely encapsulated. Using `iterator` along with recursion doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rex Kerr, thanks for your answer I tweaked a version for my own use that uses Either...  (I'm going to post it as an answer)

Comment: Probably one of the cons of _return_-based solution, is that it takes a while to realize which function it applies to: `sumEvenNumbers` or fold's `op`

Comment: @IvanBalashov - Well, it takes a while _once_ to learn what Scala's rules are for `return` (i.e., it returns from innermost explicit method you find it in), but after that it ought not take very long.  The rule is pretty clear, and the `def` gives away where the enclosing method is.

Comment: I like your foldOrFail but personally I would have made the return type `B` not `Option[B]` because then it behaves like fold where the return type is the same as the zero accumulator's type. The simply replace all the Option returns with b. and pas in None as the zero. After all the question wanted a fold that can terminate early, rather than fail.

Answer (score 28):

The scenario you describe (exit upon some unwanted condition) seems like a good use case for the `takeWhile` method. It is essentially `filter`, but should end upon encountering an element that doesn't meet the condition.

For example:

```
val list = List(2,4,6,8,6,4,2,5,3,2)
list.takeWhile(_ % 2 == 0) //result is List(2,4,6,8,6,4,2)
```

This will work just fine for `Iterator`s/`Iterable`s too. The solution I suggest for your "sum of even numbers, but break on odd" is:

```
list.iterator.takeWhile(_ % 2 == 0).foldLeft(...)
```

And just to prove that it's not wasting your time once it hits an odd number...

```
scala> val list = List(2,4,5,6,8)
list: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 5, 6, 8)

scala> def condition(i: Int) = {
     |   println("processing " + i)
     |   i % 2 == 0
     | }
condition: (i: Int)Boolean

scala> list.iterator.takeWhile(condition _).sum
processing 2
processing 4
processing 5
res4: Int = 6
```

Comment: This was exactly the kind of simplicity I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You can do what you want in a functional style using the lazy version of foldRight in scalaz. For a more in depth explanation, see [this blog post](http://voidmainargs.blogspot.de/2011/08/folding-stream-with-scala.html). While this solution uses a `Stream`, you can convert an `Iterable` into a `Stream` efficiently with `iterable.toStream`.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val str = Stream(2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
var i = 0 //only here for testing
val r = str.foldr(Some(0):Option[Int])((n,s) => {
  println(i)
  i+=1
  if (n % 2 == 0) s.map(n+) else None
})
```

This only prints

```
0
1
```

which clearly shows that the anonymous function is only called twice (i.e. until it encounters the odd number). That is due to the definition of foldr, whose signature (in case of `Stream`) is `def foldr[B](b: B)(f: (Int, => B) => B)(implicit r: scalaz.Foldable[Stream]): B`. Note that the anonymous function takes a by name parameter as its second argument, so it need no be evaluated.

Btw, you can still write this with the OP's pattern matching solution, but I find if/else and map more elegant.

Comment: What happens if you put `println` before `if`-`else` expression?

Comment: @missingfaktor: then it prints 0 and 1, but not more

Comment: @missingfaktor: since my point is easier to make this way, I changed it in the answer

Comment: Note that you can turn any iterable into a stream with `toStream`, so this answer is more general-purpose than it at first appears.

Comment: @RexKerr: Oops, forgot to mention that. Adding it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Since u r using scalaz why not use ‛0.some‛?

Answer (score 7):

Well, Scala does allow non local returns. There are differing opinions on whether or not this is a good style.

```
scala> def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]): Option[Int] = {
     |   nums.foldLeft (Some(0): Option[Int]) {
     |     case (None, _) => return None
     |     case (Some(s), n) if n % 2 == 0 => Some(s + n)
     |     case (Some(_), _) => None
     |   }
     | }
sumEvenNumbers: (nums: Iterable[Int])Option[Int]

scala> sumEvenNumbers(2 to 10)
res8: Option[Int] = None

scala> sumEvenNumbers(2 to 10 by 2)
res9: Option[Int] = Some(30)
```

**EDIT:**

In this particular case, as @Arjan suggested, you can also do:

```
def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  nums.foldLeft (Some(0): Option[Int]) {
    case (Some(s), n) if n % 2 == 0 => Some(s + n)
    case _ => return None
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of `Some(0): Option[Int]` you can just write `Option(0)`.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, yes. I just copy-pasted OP's code and did only enough modification necessary to make a point.

Answer (score 7):

[Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) has a method called [foldM](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Foldable.scala#L272) which does short-circuiting (for `Vector`, `List`, `Stream`, ...).

It works as follows:

```
def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Stream[Int]): Option[Long] = {
  import cats.implicits._
  nums.foldM(0L) {
    case (acc, c) if c % 2 == 0 => Some(acc + c)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

If it finds a not even element it returns `None` without computing the rest, otherwise it returns the sum of the even entries.

If you want to keep count until an even entry is found, you should use an `Either[Long, Long]`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `foldM` from cats lib (as suggested by @Didac) but I suggest to use `Either` instead of `Option` if you want to get actual sum out.

`bifoldMap` is used to extract the result from `Either`.

```scala
import cats.implicits._

def sumEven(nums: Stream[Int]): Either[Int, Int] = {
    nums.foldM(0) {
      case (acc, n) if n % 2 == 0 => Either.right(acc + n)
      case (acc, n) => {
        println(s"Stopping on number: $n")
        Either.left(acc)
      }
    }
  }
```

examples:

```scala
println("Result: " + sumEven(Stream(2, 2, 3, 11)).bifoldMap(identity, identity))
> Stopping on number: 3
> Result: 4

println("Result: " + sumEven(Stream(2, 7, 2, 3)).bifoldMap(identity, identity))
> Stopping on number: 7
> Result: 2
```

Comment: Came here to post a similar answer, because this is the most convenient yet still FP way to do in my opinion. I surprised that nobody votes for this. So, grab my +1.

(I prefer `(acc + n).asRight` instead of `Either.right(acc + n)` but anyway)

Comment: rather than `bifoldMap` just `fold(L => C, R => C): C` will work on `Either[L, R]`, and then you dont need a `Monoid[C]`

Answer (score 1):

@Rex Kerr your answer helped me, but I needed to tweak it to use Either

```
  
  def foldOrFail[A,B,C,D](map: B => Either[D, C])(merge: (A, C) => A)(initial: A)(it: Iterable[B]): Either[D, A] = {
    val ii= it.iterator
    var b= initial
    while (ii.hasNext) {
      val x= ii.next
      map(x) match {
        case Left(error) => return Left(error)
        case Right(d) => b= merge(b, d)
      }
    }
    Right(b)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a temporary var and using takeWhile. Here is a version.

```
  var continue = true

  // sample stream of 2's and then a stream of 3's.

  val evenSum = (Stream.fill(10)(2) ++ Stream.fill(10)(3)).takeWhile(_ => continue)
    .foldLeft(Option[Int](0)){

    case (result,i) if i%2 != 0 =>
          continue = false;
          // return whatever is appropriate either the accumulated sum or None.
          result
    case (optionSum,i) => optionSum.map( _ + i)

  }
```

The `evenSum` should be `Some(20)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A more beutiful solution would be using span:

```
val (l, r) = numbers.span(_ % 2 == 0)
if(r.isEmpty) Some(l.sum)
else None
```

... but it traverses the list two times if all the numbers are even

Comment: I like the lateral thinking exemplified by your solution, but it only solves the specific example picked in the question rather than dealing with the general question of how to terminate a fold early.

Comment: i wanted to show how to do the reverse, not terminating a fold early but only folding (in this case sum) over the values we want to fold over

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a well-chosen exception upon encountering your termination criterion, handling it in the calling code.

Comment: Scala already comes with such a feature: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/Breaks.html

Answer (score 0):

Just for an "academic" reasons (:

```
var headers = Source.fromFile(file).getLines().next().split(",")
var closeHeaderIdx = headers.takeWhile { s => !"Close".equals(s) }.foldLeft(0)((i, S) => i+1)
```

Takes twice then it should but it is a nice one liner.
If "Close" not found it will return

```
headers.size
```

Another (better) is this one:

```
var headers = Source.fromFile(file).getLines().next().split(",").toList
var closeHeaderIdx = headers.indexOf("Close")
```