# Validation with a sequence of by-name parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like to implement validation for a sequence of operations that all return `Either[Error,Item]`
It should be fail-fast (in my initial need), I mean, returning Either[Error,Seq[Item]].
If there is an error, it's obvious i do not want the following operations to be performed.
But in the future i may want to collect all the errors instead of returning only the first one.

I know Scalaz can do the job but for now I quite don't understand all parts of Scalaz and I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way to do it without using Scalaz, but using by-name parameters for exemple.

Is there a way to store by-name parameters in a sequence?
So that i can create a sequence of by-name values that represent my operations?

I mean, some kind of type `Seq[=> Either[Error,Item]]`
Then I could do something like calling takeWhile or collectFirst or something somilar, without all the operations being performed before the creation of the sequence?
I would expect the operations to be performed only when iterating on the sequence.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a `Seq[() => Either[Error, Item]]` to defer the computation at collection creation time. So for example

```
val doSomething1: () => Either[Error, Item] = () => { println(1); Right(1) }
val doSomething2: () => Either[Error, Item] = () => { println(2); Right(2) }
val doSomething3: () => Either[Error, Item] = () => { println(3); Left("error") }
val doSomething4: () => Either[Error, Item] = () => { println(4); Right(3) }
val doSomething5: () => Either[Error, Item] = () => { println(5); Left("second error") }
val l = Seq(doSomething1, doSomething2, doSomething3, doSomething4, doSomething5)
```

(`Item`s are `Int`s in the example and `Error`s are `String`s)

Then you can process them lazily stopping at first failure using the following recursive function:

```
def processUntilFailure(l: Seq[() => Either[Error, Item]]): Either[Error, Seq[Item]] = {
  l.headOption.map(_.apply() match {
    case Left(error) => Left(error)
    case Right(item)  => processUntilFailure(l.tail).right.map(_ :+ item)
  }).getOrElse(Right(Nil))
}
```

So now when I run `processUntilFailure(l)`

```
scala> processUntilFailure(l)
1
2
3
res1: Either[Error,Seq[Item]] = Left(error)
```

If you wanted to generate a `Either[Seq[String], Seq[Int]]` (processing all the operations). You could do it with a little change:

```
def processAll(l: Seq[() => Either[Error, Item]]): Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Item]] = {
  l.headOption.map(_.apply() match {
    case Left(error) => processAll(l.tail) match {
      case Right(_) => Left(Seq(error))
      case Left(previousErrors) => Left(previousErrors :+ error)
    }
    case Right(item)  => processAll(l.tail).right.map(_ :+ item)
  }).getOrElse(Right(Nil))
}
```

The only change as you can see is the Left case in the pattern match. Running this one:

```
scala> processAll(l)
1
2
3
4
5
res0: Either[Seq[Error],Seq[Item]] = Left(List(second error, error))
```

`processAll` can be replaced with a generic `foldLeft` on `l`

```
val zero: Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Item]] = Right(Seq[Item]())
l.foldLeft(zero) { (errorsOrItems: Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Item]], computation: () => Either[String, Int]) =>
  computation.apply().fold(
    { (error: String) => Left(errorsOrItems.left.toOption.map(_ :+ error).getOrElse(Seq(error))) },
    { (int: Int) => errorsOrItems.right.map(_ :+ int) })
}
```

`processUntilFailure` can as well but not easily. Since aborting early from a fold is tricky. Here's a [good answer about other possible approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892701/abort-early-in-a-fold) when you find yourself needing to do that.

Comment: I think the problem is that the Left("second error") is computed, while i do not want it to be computed, and only return the 1st error found :)

Comment: It isn't in the `processUntilFailure` function. When you run it with the list of computations only 1,2 and 3 are printed which means that `doSomething4` and `doSomething5` are never evaluated. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes that's right i misread! Finally it's kind of the same solution that has been provided by Ptharien's Flame

Answer (score 1):

You should be able  to pull this off with the type `Seq[Function0[Either[Error, Item]]]`.  `Function0` is, obviously, a zero-argument function.  The rest should be self-explanatory.

Scalaz provides the type `IO` for exactly this purpose, so you could actually use that as well.  You may not want to yet, however, if you're just beginning to work with Scalaz.