# Idiomatic "do until" collection updating

Tags: scala, collections

**Scenario**:

```
val col: IndexedSeq[Array[Char]] = for (i <- 1 to n) yield {
   val x = for (j <- 1 to m) yield 'x'
   x.toArray
}
```

This is a fairly simple char matrix. `toArray` used to allow updating.

```
  var west = last.x - 1
  while (west >= 0 && arr(last.y)(west) == '.') {
      arr(last.y)(west) = ch;
      west -= 1;
  }
```

This is updating all `.` to `ch` until a non-dot char is found.

Generically, update until stop condition is met, unknown number of steps.

What is the idiomatic equivalent of it?

**Conclusion**

It's doable, but the trade-off isn't worth it, a lot of performance is lost to expressive syntax when the collection allows updating.

Comment: Array[String]? it seems to me there should be Array[Char].

Comment: Is in-place updating a requirement?

Comment: write a recursive method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wish for a "cleaner, more idiomatic" solution is of course a little fuzzy, because it leaves a lot of room for subjectivity. In general, I'd consider a tail-recursive updating routine more idiomatic, but it might not be "cleaner" if you're more familiar with a non-functional programming style. I came up with this:

```
@tailrec
def update(arr:List[Char], replace:Char, replacement:Char, result:List[Char] = Nil):List[Char] = arr match {
    case `replace` :: tail =>
        update(tail, replace, replacement, replacement :: result)
    case _ => result.reverse ::: arr
}
```

This takes one of the inner sequences (assuming a `List` for easier pattern matching, since Arrays are trivially convertible to lists), and replaces the `replace` char with the `replacement` recursively.

You can then use map to update the outer sequence, like so:

```
col.map { x => update(x, '.', ch) }
```

---

Another more reusable alternative is writing your own `mapUntil`, or using one which is implemented in a supplemental library (Scalaz probably has something like it). The one I came up with looks like this:

```
def mapUntil[T](input:List[T])(f:(T => Option[T])) = {
    @tailrec
    def inner(xs:List[T], result:List[T]):List[T] = xs match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case head :: tail => f(head) match {
            case None => (head :: result).reverse ::: tail
            case Some(x) => inner(tail, x :: result)
        }
    }

    inner(input, Nil)
}
```

It does the same as a regular `map` invocation, except that it stops as soon as the passed function returns `None`, e.g.

```
mapUntil(List(1,2,3,4)) {
    case x if x >= 3 => None
    case x => Some(x-1)
}
```

Will result in

```
List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3, 4)
```

---

If you want to look at Scalaz, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12893459/124257) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Please note that I wrote up the `mapUntil` implementation just now and it might very well contain a hidden "gift" (read: bug). If you're planning on using it in production, I'd definitely whip up a couple of unit tests for it ;)

Comment: I have no idea what to make of your last comment. Could you clarify?   I'd be interested in some concrete data on how much slower `mapUntil` actually is, and why you'd want to use `update` on a list.

Answer (score 2):

x3ro's answer is the right answer, esp. if you care about performance or are going to be using this operation in multiple places. I would like to add simple solution using only what you find in the collections API:

```
col.map { a =>
  val (l, r) = a.span(_ == '.')
  l.map {
    case '.' => ch
    case x => x
  } ++ r
}
```

Comment: `span` instead of the `takeWhile`/`dropWhile` combo?

Comment: @SethTisue I thought there was a method for that! I didn't find it when I went to look, I kept searching for something like splitWhile. Edited.