# Scala takeWhile Method with foldLeft and foldRight

Tags: scala

I need to make takeWhile() using foldLeft() and foldRight().
I've come up with this:

```
def takeWhile(ls:List[Int], p:Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
    ls.foldLeft(List[Int]())(a,z) =>
    if (p(z)) z :: a
    else a)
}

def takeWhile(ls:List[Int], p:Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
    ls.foldRight(List[Int]())(a,z) =>
    if (p(a)) a :: z
    else z)
}
```

But with foldLeft when I call

```
takeWhile(List(1,2,3,4,5), _< 3)
takeWhile(List(1,2,3,4,5), _> 4)
takeWhile(List(5,6,7,1,2,5), _> 4)
```

It returns

```
List(2,1)
List(5)
List(5,7,6,5)
```

With foldRight I get

```
List(5)
List(5,6,7,5)
```

But it should be

```
List(1,2)
List()
List(5,6,7)
```

How do I make it stop when condition is not met?

Comment: No doubt you have your reasons for re-inventing takeWhile. I think what you will need to do is to make your accumulator a tuple of List[Int] and Boolean. As long as the latter is true, you will continue. Finally, of course you will want to extract just the List[Int] for your result. Your operator will now be a bit more complex, of course. Also, you might want to try inverting z :: a and a :: z.

Comment: Do you have to use the fold* methods?  They aren't designed for this, they loop the entire collection.  If you are set on using a fold, you can do things like call return or maybe throw an exception to exit early.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892701/abort-early-in-a-fold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is the following (pretty much the same as you did it):

```
def takeWhile(ls:List[Int], p:Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
    ls.foldLeft(List[Int]()){
      case (a,z) =>
      if (p(z)) z :: a
      else return a.reverse
    }
}
```

It prints the following:

```
List(1, 2)
List()
List(5, 6, 7)
```

The `return` Returns from the takeWhile-method, so it does what you want, because it stops the `foldLeft`-operation.

Sorry I modified your Code (other brackets etc), but it didn't compile when copying.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get foldLeft() to work. It's hacky, but it gets the job done and it's a starting point:

```
def takeWhile(ls:List[Int], p:Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  ls.foldLeft((List[Int](), true)) {
    (a, z) =>
      if (a._2 && p(z)) (z :: a._1, a._2)
      else (a._1, false)
  }._1.reverse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using `foldRight` (since you asked for both):

```
def takeWhile[T](list: List[T], p: T => Boolean) =
  list.foldRight(List.empty[T]){
    case (t, l) if p(t) => t :: l
    case (t, l) => Nil
  }
```

It reinitialize the state to `Nil` whenever it finds a  value that should not be taken.