# Does Scala intelligently terminate calculating OR expressions for fold operations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections, monads

Suppose you have a value `val list: List[Date]`. You would like to know if any one of the dates in this list occur after some `startDate`. You could do this

```
  list.fold(false)((a, b) => startDate.compareTo(b) < 0 || a)
```

which would return `true` if any date occurred on or after `startDate` thus achieving our objective.

However, since this is an OR statement being used, if even only one date satisfies the condition `startDate.compareTo(b) < 0`, then the whole fold operation will return `true`. Does Scala have a way of terminating execution of the fold and just returning the `true` when it hits it?

Comment: You may use `exists` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a usecase for `exists`.

```
list.exists(a => startDate.compareTo(a) < 0)
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#exists(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean

Answer (score 4):

> However, since this is an OR statement being used, if even only one date satisfies the condition startDate.compareTo(b) < 0, then the whole fold operation will return true.

Actually, not necessarily; `startDate.compareTo(b) < 0` could throw an exception. You'd need to change the order of operands to `(a, b) => a || startDate.compareTo(b) < 0`; even then it would be correct for a `List`, but not e.g. a `Stream`.

At any rate, as far as I know the answer is no even for the cases where it's correct. `fold` can't see inside the function it receives, only call it, so it would require specific support for this case in the compiler.

See also: [Abort early in a fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892701/abort-early-in-a-fold) and https://users.scala-lang.org/t/breaking-out-of-a-map-or-other-iteration/1091.