# Abort early in a fold with ZIO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold, zio

I wanted to add an answer to [abort-early-in-a-fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892701/abort-early-in-a-fold) for **ZIO**.

So I took the solution with cats: [cats solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52781136/2750966)

```
def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Stream[Int]): Option[Long] = {
  import cats.implicits._
  nums.foldM(0L) {
    case (acc, c) if c % 2 == 0 => Some(acc + c)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

How can this be achieved with ***ZIO***?

The closest I got:

```
  new DefaultRuntime {}
    .unsafeRun(sumEvenNumbers(List(2,4,6,3,5,6)))

  def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]): ZIO[Any, Nothing, Int] = {
    stream.Stream.fromIterable(nums)
      .run(Sink.fold(0)(s => s % 2 == 0) { (a: Int, b: Int) => (a + b, Chunk.empty)
      })
  }
```

But that gives me: `15` instead of `12`. So it seems to short circuit but it takes a number too many. And it is an `Int` not `Option[Int]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without `zio.stream.Stream`:

```scala
  def sumEvenNumbers(as: Iterable[Int]): UIO[Option[Int]] =
    ZIO
      .foldLeft(as)(0)((s, a) => if (a % 2 == 0) ZIO.succeed(s + a) else ZIO.fail(s))
      .option
```

- Use `.foldLeft` - as soon as a number is not even - the fold fails.
- Use `.option` to merge the Error channel to the Success channel to an `Option`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `takeWhile` and then `fold`:

```
import zio._
import zio.stream._

object Foo extends zio.App {
  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[zio.ZEnv, Nothing, Int] =
    Stream
      .fromIterable(List(2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 6))
      .takeWhile(_ % 2 == 0)
      .fold(0L)(_ + _)
      // Just to print the output before terminating
      .flatMap(res => zio.console.putStrLn(res.toString) *> ZIO.succeed(0))
}
```

I don't see a reason for this to return an `Option[Long]`.

Comment: > I don't see a reason for this to return an Option[Long]. / I think that is the exception handling. so if not all numbers are even return with None > Exception.

Comment: @pme Why would uneven numbers trigger an exception?

Comment: As always maybe hard to find a good example;). See the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892701/abort-early-in-a-fold

Answer (score 1):

With the idea of *@Yuval Itzchakov* and my remark that `Option` is to express an *Exception* (`None`).

I came up with this solution:

```
  def sumEvenNumbers(nums: Iterable[Int]): UIO[Option[Int]] = {
    Stream.fromIterable(nums)
      .run(Sink.foldLeftM(0) { (acc: Int, b: Int) =>
        if (b % 2 == 0)
          ZIO.succeed(acc + b)
        else
          ZIO.fail(acc)
      }).fold(
      _ => None, 
      v => Some(v)
    )
  }
```

- Use `foldLeftM` - as soon as a number is not even - the fold fails.
- Fold the result to `Option`